# Tizen SDK installation failure

Tags: tizen, tizen-install

I downloaded Tizen installer package ( windows 7 64 bit ) from this [link](https://developer.tizen.org/downloads/tizen-sdk) and tizen windows image file (beta) from this [link](http://download.tizen.org/sdk/sdk-images/2.3b/). I clicked advanced in installer manager, extracted the image into installer and installed it.
But it returned errors. I checked install-log file. Here is the error:

```
13:06:57 [TRACE] [LoggerShellParser     ( 101)] -   [version-manager] 'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
13:06:57 [TRACE] [LoggerShellParser     ( 101)] -   [version-manager] operable program or batch file.
13:06:57 [TRACE] [ShellUtil             ( 129)] -   Command exit code => 255
13:06:57 [ERROR] [Installer             ( 607)] - Installer.executeScript() install script error => C:\tizen-sdk\temp\Install.bat
13:06:57 [ERROR] [Installer             ( 609)] - Exit code => 255
13:06:57 [ERROR] [IMFatalException      (  48)] - Fatal error occurred while executing post script. (temp package)
13:06:57 [ERROR] [IMFatalException      (  48)] - Fatal error occurred while executing install script.
(version-manager package)
13:06:57 [ERROR] [InstallManager        ( 952)] - Installation failed => version-manager
13:06:57 [ERROR] [IMFatalException      (  48)] - Fatal error occurred while executing install script.
(version-manager package)
13:06:57 [INFO ] [InstallManager        (1446)] - Remove all packages.
13:06:57 [INFO ] [InstallManager        (1344)] - Remove package start  => intelhaxm
13:06:57 [INFO ] [Installer             ( 416)] - [intelhaxm] uninstall start
13:06:57 [INFO ] [Installer             ( 547)] - executeRemoveScript => Remove.bat
13:06:57 [INFO ] [Installer             ( 429)] - This package does not need a remove script.
13:06:57 [INFO ] [InstallManager        (1372)] - [intelhaxm] remove end => true
13:06:57 [INFO ] [InstallManager        (1344)] - Remove package start  => sdb
13:06:57 [INFO ] [Installer             ( 416)] - [sdb] uninstall start
13:06:57 [INFO ] [Installer             ( 547)] - executeRemoveScript => Remove.bat
13:06:57 [INFO ] [Installer             ( 582)] - Execute script starts...
13:06:57 [TRACE] [Installer             ( 592)] -   Current working directory. => C:\tizen-sdk\.info\sdb
13:06:57 [INFO ] [ShellUtil             ( 110)] - execute command => [cmd.exe, /C, C:\tizen-sdk\.info\sdb\Remove.bat]
13:06:57 [ERROR] [InstallManager        ( 876)] - download failed => file:/C:/Users/Arpita/AppData/Local/.installmanager/install-manager/download/tizen-sdk-image-TizenSDK_2.3.0b2-windows64.zip///binary/base-native-ide-product_2.3.16_windows-64.zip
13:06:57 [ERROR] [IMFatalException      (  48)] - Download canceled.
13:06:57 [ERROR] [ViewController        ( 351)] - throwing
org.tizen.installmanager.core.IMFatalException: Download canceled.
    at org.tizen.installmanager.core.InstallManager.downloadPackage(InstallManager.java:891) ~[rsrc:./:?]
    at org.tizen.installmanager.core.InstallManager.install(InstallManager.java:751) ~[rsrc:./:?]
    at org.tizen.installmanager.core.InstallManager.install(InstallManager.java:641) ~[rsrc:./:?]
    at org.tizen.installmanager.ui.page.ViewController.install(ViewController.java:336) [rsrc:./:?]
    at org.tizen.installmanager.ui.page.InstallingPage.installProcess(InstallingPage.java:336) [rsrc:./:?]
    at org.tizen.installmanager.ui.page.InstallingPage$InstallThread.run(InstallingPage.java:301) [rsrc:./:?]
13:06:57 [ERROR] [IMFatalException      (  48)] - Download canceled.
13:06:57 [ERROR] [InstallingPage        ( 346)] - Fatal error occurred while executing install script.
(version-manager package)
13:06:57 [ERROR] [InstallingPage        ( 350)] - Installation failed
13:06:57 [INFO ] [ErrorController       ( 291)] - Set installation success: false
```

How can I work around findstr issue and related issue?
P.S: I've java 1.8 in my system and my system's RAM is 2GB. I checked install requirements, it says that at least 3 GB RAM is required. Does this have any adverse effect on installation procedure?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because of beta version and i hope you are having windows 7 (64 bit). And as for the RAM issue, I don't think it will create any problem as in my friend laptop the RAM is only 2 GB and SDK is working fine on his system.

I don't know it will going to help for sure, but you can also try setting JAVA_HOME path in environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check you PATH. findstr is in C:\Windows\system32\ - your path should point there. There are many solutions for this issue if you google. This is quite common. This is why your installation fails.
Second: why you use beta? Recent release is [rev1](http://download.tizen.org/sdk/sdk-images/2.3_Rev1/tizen-sdk-image-TizenSDK_2.3.0_Rev1-windows32.zip). Please use it.